# How to move a struct with promise inside it?

Tags: c++, copy, promise, move

Recently I have read a part of "Concurrency in action" book concerning parallel quicksort implementation. I tried to check the code mentioned in the book and received an error on this part:

```
struct listPart
{
    list<T> data;
    promise<list<T>> promise;
};
listPart newLowerPart;
...
parts.push(move(newLowerPart));
```

The compiler gives the error

> std::promise::promise(const std::promise> &) : attempting
>   to reference a deleted function.

The error is occured in generated copy constructor of listPart. 
I guess trying to move newLowerPart it tries to use deleted copy constructor of promise. I thought creating custom copy constructor would help, but even an attempt to move promise inside it gave me the same error. Could you help me to solve this problem?
Thank you in advance

Comment: @0x499602D2 It's a threadsafe stack of listPart.

Comment: And does `parts.push` handle rvalue references correctly?

Comment: @user1536810: How is that implemented? Does it try to copy its elements? Can we see the relevant parts of it (preferably as part of a [complete test case](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve))? Do you get the same error if you don't involve that, e.g. if you just do `listPart test = move(newLowerPart)`?

Comment: Compiles fine for me http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ba26917c8c79fc8f

Comment: @Mike Seymour yes, I get the same error if I just do listPart test = move(newLowerPart). If I comment this part, everything's fine so I don't really think it's stack's fault. Moreover, the author recommended to use implementation of the stack from his book and that's what I did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember, that correct handling rvalues requires special treatment. So your container should provide at least two versions of `push`:

```
void push(const T& t); //'t' is coopied
```

and

```
void push(T&& t); //'t' is moved
```

Also, you should define move constructor for `listPart` and forbid copying:

Solution:

```
struct listPart
{
    list<T> data;
    promise<list<T>> promise;

    listPart(const listPart&) = delete;

    listPart(listPart&& source)
    : data(std::move(source.data))
    , promise(std::move(source.promise))
    {  }
};
```

> I thought creating custom copy constructor would help

As I demonstrated, you shouldn't define copy constructor for `listPart` - it should either be deleted or (in case of pre-C++ 11) private with no implementation provided. That's because copying [std::promise](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/promise/promise) is not defined (its copy constructor is deleted), so copying instance of `listPart` is meaningless in this case.

Comment: I tried to delete copy constructor and create move constructor before. It is also essential to add listPart() = default. And you all were right: the problem was in parts not taking X&& parameter. I changed the stack implementation a bit and everything worked. Thank you for detailed answer!

Answer (score 2):

The problem is likely with your `parts` container implementation - it tries to copy the `push` parameter instead of moving it.
[Here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e70bb62fc151b885) is an example:

```
#include <list>
#include <future>

struct listPart
{
    std::list<int> data;
    std::promise<std::list<int>> p;
};
template<typename T>
class dummy_container{
T t_;
public:
    void push_back(const T& t){
        t_ = t;       
    }
    void move_back(const T& t){
        t_ = t;    
    }
    void move_back(T&& t){
        t_ = std::move(t);    
    }
};

int main() {
    dummy_container<listPart> dc;
    listPart lp;
    //dc.push_back(std::move(lp)); // won't compile, function only handles const references
    dc.move_back(std::move(lp)); // will compile, because it moves if possible
}
```